# In Tailwind, how to set height of a div to 80% of the screen?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have an overflow div in `y` axis and want it to be exactly the 80% of the height of the screen. Now I have this `<div class="overflow-y-auto h-96">` which works but the height must be bigger than 96, exactly 80% of the whole screen (to leave space for header and footer).

Using `h-4/5` seems not to work.

```
    <div class="h-4/5 bg-yellow-200 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="overflow-y-auto bg-yellow-500 space-y-3">
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update:
I got this (also available here https://play.tailwindcss.com/NlZdzWfkyD) but if I uncomment the topbar it fails, please, any idea?

```
<div class="h-screen">
  <div class="h-full">
    <!--<div class="bg-blue-400 py-3">topbar</div>-->

    <div class="pl-6 pr-16 pt-12 h-full">
      <div class="h-full border border-gray-200 rounded-t-xl px-20 pt-3 flex flex-col">
        <div class="h-1/2 bg-red-100"></div>
        <div class="h-1/2">
          <div class="flex flex-col h-full">
            <div class="bg-yellow-200 overflow-hidden">
              <div class="overflow-y-auto bg-blue-500 space-y-3 h-full">
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
                <div class="bg-blue-300 h-48"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="h-20"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'h-4/5' there is a class. It is `height: 80%`. If you want exactly 80 of screen you should put new size of `height: 80vh`.

Comment: thanks, but it seems to not work, still scrolls down, I added some code, please if you could help me

Comment: Did you try that `height: 80vh` too?

Comment: Or you can put header and footer fixed. So you wouldn't worry about content

Comment: I got this which is working as I want https://play.tailwindcss.com/D6kRDFPTAr but when uncomment the topbar code it scrolls down that space (of the topbar height). Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use "mt-" ?

Comment: mt- in which div? sorry, I'm new to tailwind

Comment: mt it's margin-top so you should put it in content div. In docs sizes of mt so you should read docs [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin)

Comment: yeah, but in the outer div? in the first one? sorry, I'm trying to add a margin top or a negative margin top but it doesn't fit. If you could have a look please, when you could

Answer (score 32):

You can do `h-[80vh]`, which would set the height to 80% of the screen height.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with tailwindcss V3.3.3: You can do `h-[80%]`, `h-[xx%]` which set the height or `w-[xx%]` set the Width of the element.

Also we have `h-3/6 <- height: 50%; h-x/x or   w-3/6<-width: 50%; w-x/x`